# Best way to protect against SQL injection in SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

Hello I'm wondering what is the best way to protect against `SQL injection` in `SqlDataAdapter` (as there is no way to use parameterized query)?

For example lets use this part of code:

```
da_services = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from table WHERE column='" + textBox1.Text + "' AND column2='" + somestring + "'", conn);
scd_services = new SqlCommandBuilder(da_services);
dt_services = new DataTable();
da_services.Fill(dt_services);
dtg_services.DataSource = dt_services;
conn.Close();
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: *as there is no way to use parametrized query.* [Uh.......](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try accessing the SqlCommand object of the DataAdapter:

```
da_services = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from table WHERE column=@column AND column2=@column2", conn);
da_services.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", textBox1.Text);
da_services.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column2", somestring);
```