# Use inner join with C# SQL Server (Retrieving data from multiple table using SQL query and inner join in C# ADO.NET)

Tags: c#, sql-server, join, ado.net, inner-join

Am trying to retrieve data from two different tables into a datatable and to assign into textboxes in C# WinForms. Though I succeeded with this query when I tried it in SQL Server but implementing it on WinForms is what I don't know.
This is what have tried in my code:

```
 string supplier_id = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("select New_Supplier.Supplier_Name, New_Supplier.Address, New_Supplier.City, New_Supplier.Contact_No ,Purchase_Entry.Balance from New_Supplier,Purchase_Entry where New_Supplier.'" + supplier_id + "' = Purchase_Entry.'" + supplier_id + "' ", con);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); cmd.Fill(dt);
                    Purchase_Entry.Instance.txtsuppliername.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    Purchase_Entry.Instance.txtaddress.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                    Purchase_Entry.Instance.txtcity.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                    Purchase_Entry.Instance.txtcontactno.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
                    Purchase_Entry.Instance.lblbalance.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
```

Tried this also:

```
 string supplier_id = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(); MessageBox.Show(supplier_id);
                    SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter($"select New_Supplier.Supplier_Name, New_Supplier.Address, New_Supplier.City, New_Supplier.Contact_No ,Purchase_Entry.Balance from New_Supplier,Purchase_Entry where New_Supplier.{supplier_id} = Purchase_Entry.{supplier_id} ", con);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); cmd.Fill(dt);
                    Purchase_Entry.Instance.txtsuppliername.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    Purchase_Entry.Instance.txtaddress.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                    Purchase_Entry.Instance.txtcity.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                    Purchase_Entry.Instance.txtcontactno.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
                    Purchase_Entry.Instance.lblbalance.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
```

But am having error concatenating the query when fetching data
Tried this in SQL Server and it works

```
select New_Supplier.Supplier_Name, New_Supplier.Address, New_Supplier.City, New_Supplier.Contact_No ,Purchase_Entry.Balance from New_Supplier,Purchase_Entry where New_Supplier.supplier_id = Purchase_Entry.supplier_id
```

and it returned me back what I want:

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Invalid column name 's' for the second try below @Dale K

Comment: why you substitute supplier_id 
New_Supplier.{supplier_id} = Purchase_Entry.{supplier_id}

Comment: @john..Actually i got the supplier id from a datagridview column and initialize it into a string. since the first code i write didnt work.......the first code up there error is Incorrect syntax

Comment: @user3401335 am working on winforms so i needed to specify which supplier id i need

Comment: Having 'supplier_id' as the name of the column and your param variable can lead to confusion.  Perhaps change the first line (in ex. 1) to `string supplierID = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();`.  Then, you want something like `"... where New_Supplier.supplier_id = Purchase_Entry.supplier_id and New_Supplier.supplier_id = " + supplierID;`  in your query

Comment: Evolve - no one should be using [old style joins via the where clause](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you should write like this

```
SqlDataAdapter cmd =new SqlDataAdapter(
                    "select 
                    New_Supplier.Supplier_Name,
                    New_Supplier.Address,
                    New_Supplier.City,
                    New_Supplier.Contact_No,
                    Purchase_Entry.Balance
                    from New_Supplier,Purchase_Entry 
                    where New_Supplier.supplier_id = Purchase_Entry.supplier_id
                    and New_Supplier.supplier_id='"+supplier_id +"'
                 ", con);
```

or

```
SqlDataAdapter cmd =new SqlDataAdapter(
                    "select 
                    New_Supplier.Supplier_Name,
                    New_Supplier.Address,
                    New_Supplier.City,
                    New_Supplier.Contact_No,
                    Purchase_Entry.Balance
                    from New_Supplier
                    inner join Purchase_Entry on New_Supplier.supplier_id = 
                    Purchase_Entry.supplier_id
                    where New_Supplier.supplier_id='"+supplier_id +"'
                 ", con);
```

but it's better to use SQL parameter instead of concate string because of SQL injection as shown below:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
     @"select 
            New_Supplier.Supplier_Name,
            New_Supplier.Address,
            New_Supplier.City,
            New_Supplier.Contact_No,
            Purchase_Entry.Balance
            from New_Supplier
            inner join Purchase_Entry on New_Supplier.supplier_id = 
            Purchase_Entry.supplier_id
            where New_Supplier.supplier_id= @supplier_id", con);
    
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supplier_id",SqlDbType.Int).Value = supplier_id;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Comment: Never ever concate strings in an SQL query, you're just asking to be hacked. What is SQL injection: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp How to code a safe solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078072/best-way-to-protect-against-sql-injection-in-sqldataadapter

Comment: Have you tested it if you supply `string supplier_id = "' OR 1 = 1 ; DROP TABLE New_Supplier ; -- "`?

Comment: I know about SQL Injection Completely, and I know that is better to use Parameter instead of concate string in SQL query, but I just tried to solve the problem easier, at the level of his knowledge and his need

Answer (score 2):

The query could be like

```
    select supplier.Supplier_Name, supplier.Address, supplier.City, 
           supplier.Contact_No, purchase.Balance 
    from New_Supplier supplier 
    join Purchase_Entry purchase on supplier.supplier_id = purchase.supplier_id
    where purchase.supplier_id = @SupplierId
```

I suggest to use [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) in order to avoid Sql Injection

```
cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@SupplierId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = supplier_id ;
```

You can use also ORM to map the query to an object, like [dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper)

because mapping with datatable with array is a little huge. If you change the query and the order of your select, could display the wrong data

Comment: don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)